# Implementing player to player trading with custom heads through dropped in Minecraft 1.19.3

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I already asked this question a few months ago but I will ask it again because this time it is even more specific.

So I have a player to player trading system for custom head where if you drop a specific item it will spawn an armor stand under which a dropper is placed. In this dropper is the trading UI which looks like this:

[image: The green and the red concrete are accept and decline. The glas panes are just filler]

Player 1 will place a head in the first empty slot and player 2 will put it in the second slot. To ensure that the other player can't take the other head away, the armor stand that spawns the dropper will get the two items from the slots in the main and offhand. The items inside the two slots both get a different enchantment to differentiate them. If a player tries to take a head from the other slot it will be removed from his inventory and since the armor stand has the two items in his hands I can copy it back in the now empty slot. To differentiate the players i made it so that the first one to interact with the dropper will be set to player one and the second one to player two. The dropper then gets locked to prevent a third player from interacting.

[image: You can see the armor stand holding an item]

Now to my problem:
I don't know why but somehow when I use the armor stand to put the item back into the slot after the other player tries to take it using data merge Minecraft doesn't allow me to select the slot in which the item is placed it just automatically goes in the first slot.

Is there a better solution to make this system overall or does someone know how to solve the data merge problem? I also don't want to use plugins or data packs.

the commands look like this:

for the armor stand hand:

1. `execute at @e[name=TRADE,limit=1] run data modify entity  @e[name=TRADE,limit=1] HandItems[0] set from block ~ ~-1 ~  Items[{Slot:0b}]`
2. `execute at @e[name=TRADE,limit=1] run data modify entity  @e[name=TRADE,limit=1] HandItems[-1] set from block ~ ~-1 ~  Items[{Slot:2b}]`

for the placing back:

1. `execute at @e[name=TRADE,limit=1] run data modify block  ~ ~-1 ~ Items[{Slot:2b}] set from entity @e[name=TRADE,limit=1]  HandItems[-1]`
2. `execute at @e[name=TRADE,limit=1] run data modify block  ~ ~-1 ~ Items[{Slot:0b}] set from entity @e[name=TRADE,limit=1]  HandItems[0]`

I also have the commands that place the glass and the concrete inside the hopper and give the two trade items the enchantments but they work.
Then I also had to make the UI disappear for a short time when someone tries to take out the other players item because Minecraft won't allow me to `/data merge` unless the dropper is empty for some reason.

Comment: (The aforementioned already asked question presumably is [How do I prevent other players from taking items out of a dropper? (1.18.2)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/396850/185203))

Comment: I think it's easier to transfer items using /Item
https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commands/item